# Prove that the set {$\rightarrow, \oplus$} is functionally complete by using that it is {$+, \neg$}

Tags: functions, discrete-mathematics, logic, boolean-algebra, boolean

The set {$+, \neg$} is functionally complete, because every boolean function can be represented as only combination of Disjunctions ($+$) and Negations ($\neg$).

Prove that the set {$\rightarrow, \oplus$} is functionally complete by using that it is {$+, \neg$}

---

I'm a bit confused by this question. I know that in boolean logic, $a \rightarrow b$ is equivalent to $\neg a + b$, but what about $\oplus$ ? And how should I proceed ?

---

EDIT: First, there was a typo in the post (I wrote {$\rightarrow, \neg$} instead of {$+, \neg$}) that was now corrected. Hopefully it makes more sense now.

And I found the solution of the same exercise of last year. It says:

"Because every function can be represented with $+$ and $\neg$, it is sufficient to show that $+$ and $\neg$ can each be represented with $\rightarrow$ and $\oplus$. $\neg x=1\oplus x =(x \rightarrow x) \oplus x$ and $x + y= \neg x \rightarrow y =((x \rightarrow x) \oplus x) \rightarrow y$"

This solution seems kind of confusing to me, what they did kind of makes sense but I have no idea how to find that solution myself without help

Comment: $\oplus$ is the exclusive or, right?

Comment: @Milten Yes, it's XOR

Comment: Note that $\neg p$ may be defined as  $(p \to (q ⊕ q))$.

Comment: No wonder you are confused by the question – it's nonsense. Are you sure you have written it out exactly the way it was given?

Comment: @GerryMyerson The exercise translated from German says: The set {$\rightarrow, \neg$} is functionally complete, because every boolean function can be represented as only combination of Disjunctions ($+$) and Negations ($\neg$).

i. Represent the constant Zero Function $f(x_1, ... x_n) = 0$ only with compositions of Disjunctions and Negations
ii. Prove that the set {$\rightarrow, \oplus$} is functionally complete (German: "funktional vollständig") by using that it is {$+, \neg$}

For i., it's easy to see $0 = \neg(x_1 + \neg x_1)$ where $+$ represents logical OR. For ii, see next comment

Comment: There is a typo in the first sentence, they probably meant $\{+, \neg\}$. The set $\{\to, \oplus\}$ is **not** $\{+, \neg\}$, these two sets are distinct; you need to show that the 1st set *generates* the whole set of B. functions, via reduction to the second set, which is known to be functionally complete. So there must be a formula 1 built using $\{\to, \oplus\}$ that expresses $+$, and a formula 2 for $\neg$ (this is given above). In OP you started doing the opposite of what is needed. Here you can write out the truth tables and guess the combination. Say compute $(a\to b)\to b$...

Comment: @GerryMyerson For ii, I found the solution of last year for the same exercise, and it says: Because every function can be represented with $+$ and $\neg$, it is sufficient to show that $+$ and $\neg$ can each be represented with $\rightarrow$ and $\oplus$. $\neg x = 1 \oplus x = (x \rightarrow x) \oplus x$ and $x + y = \neg x \rightarrow y = ((x \rightarrow x ) \oplus x ) \rightarrow y$

Comment: @GerryMyerson Their solution for last year makes kind of sense, but I have no idea how I am supposed to find it out myself, it seems more of a trick to me than anything else

Comment: @Amateur_Algebraist I found the solution of the same exercise for last year, see my comment above. But the solution seems kind of confusing

Comment: @Amateur_Algebraist Uh, I see what you mean, yes there was a typo in my question above, it should be {$+, \neg$}, not {$\rightarrow, \neg$}, I corrected it, thank you for pointing it out

Comment: @GerryMyerson there was a typo in my question above, it should be {$+, \neg$}, not {$\rightarrow, \neg$}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is, indeed, a trick; for a general functionally complete set $S$, you can't expect to have a non-bruteforce algorithm to express a given Boolean function in terms of $S$. That is a hard task. One (but not the main) aspect is that there is no uniqueness (see my prev. comment and yours that contain different formulae for $x+y$). Some choices of $S$, however, behave better, and later in the course you shall see examples such as CNF, DNF, or Zhegalkin polynomials. In many useful aspects, for an arbitrary function these normal forms are *way* easier to understand than an expression in terms of $S = \{\to, \oplus\}$.

Answer (score 4):

It's a little bit of trial and error, for sure, but I wouldn't say it's quite a 'trick' either.

For example, given $\to$, it's fairly natural to think of what $x \to x$ would be, and you'll see that $x \to x = 1$. Likewise, you find that $x \oplus x = 0$.

OK, so now you have $1$ and $0$ to play with, so now you can try expressions like $x \to 0$ or $0 \oplus x$ or $x \oplus 1$ or ... . So doing that, you'll quickly find that $x \to 0$, $1 \oplus x$, and $x \oplus 1$ all work out to work like $\neg x$.

Great! $\neg$ was one of the operators you were looking for, so now you know how to express it using $\to$ and $\oplus$: following the answer from last year: $\neg x = 1 \oplus x = (x \to x) \oplus x$.  But you could also have used $\neg x = x \oplus 1 = x \oplus (x \to x)$. Or: $\neg x = x \to 0 = x \to (x \oplus x)$

Now, what about the $+$?  Here, we can use a well-known equivalence $x \to y = \neg x + y$, which means that $x + y = \neg x \to y$.  So, plug in any of the expressions for $\neg x$ that already found, and you're there.  Following the 'answer from last year': $x + y = \neg x \to y = ((x \to x) \oplus x) \to y$.  But you could also have used $x + y = \neg x \to y = (x \oplus (x \to x)) \to y$, or $x + y = \neg x \to y = (x \to (x \oplus x)) \to y$

So yeah, the end results look complicated, and you may think 'How on earth could I have come up with that?!', but the process was actually pretty straightforward.